# How to add ondragstart=“drag(event)” to a dynamically created elements (li)?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Examples:

list tag created dynamically:

```
var newli = document.createElement('li');
newli.id = "fstId";
```

How do you give this list tag the property " ondragstart="drag(event)" "?

please advise me...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag & Drop are event that are passed down to any DOM elements. While creating a element dynamically you first have to enable its draggable property & add event for drag & other events flowed by in Drag & Drop you can find it in details below

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Further you can add those event & flag like this given below,

```
var node = document.createElement("li"); 
node.draggable = true;
node.addEventListener('drag', setDragging);
```

Here setDraging is a callback function on which you have to describe what to do when dragging. You can find the complete implementation below here but its better to go first to previous link I described above. Here is the full implementation,

1. https://medium.com/better-programming/create-a-sortable-list-with-draggable-items-using-javascript-9ef38f96b258